# Помогите написать алгоритм для Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Привет. Есть алгоритм, который берёт все картинки(и сжимает их), все стили(минифицирует и объединяет в один) и скрипты - объединяет в один. Для полного счастья мне не хватает одного функционала. У меня есть папка `/src/`, в которой лежит `app.js`, а рядом с ним ещё папка `/js-modules/`. Что мне нужно, так это сперва обработать app.js при помощи Babel(чтобы код транспилировался с ES5), а затем объединить его с файлами в папке `/js-modules/`. Как обработать файл при помощи Babel я знаю, но вот как его же потом прикрепить к файлам из папки - не могу разобраться.

**gilpfile.js**:

```
'use strict';

const del = require('del');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const uglify = requrire('gulp-uglify');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task("babelify", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("../assets/js/"));
});

const paths = {
    scripts: 'src/js-modules/*.js',
    images: 'src/img/*',
    styles: 'src/css/*.css'
}

function clean() {
    return del(['build']);
}

function images() {
    return gulp.src(paths.images)
    .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../assets/img'))
}

function scripts() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('modules.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../assets/js'))
}

function styles() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename('style.css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../assets/css'))
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch(paths.scripts, scripts);
    gulp.watch(paths.images, images);
    gulp.watch(paths.styles, styles);
}

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
    clean,
    gulp.parallel(scripts, images, styles)
));
gulp.task(clean);
gulp.task(watch);

gulp.task('default', gulp-series('build'));
```

Comment: подавайте на вход таске scripts все файлы src/**/*.js, а как подключать gulp-babel думаю разберетесь

Answer (score 0):

В таске Scripts где происходит concat в src добавить путь до собранного Babel файла:

```
gulp.src([paths.scripts,'путь до обработаннго babel файла'])
```